# Initialize array of char in initialization list of constructor in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, class, initialization-list

Is it ok to use initialization like this?

```
class Foo
{
public:
   Foo() : str("str") {}
   char str[4];
};
```

And this?

```
int main()
{
   char str[4]("str");
}
```

Both give me an error in gcc 4.7.2:

> error: array used as initializer

Comeau compiles both.

Comment: clang also compiles both of these in C++03 mode.

Answer (score 5):

In C++03, the non-static member array cannot be initialized as you mentioned. In g++ may be you can have an extension of *initializer list*, but that's a C++11 feature.

Local variable in a function can be initialized like this:

```
char str[] = "str"; // (1)
char str[] = {'s','t','r',0}; // (2)
```

Though you can mention the dimension as `4`, but it's better *not mentioned* to avoid accidental array out of bounds.

I would recommend to use `std::string` in both the cases.

Comment: Comeau compiles both in C++03 mode, why?

Comment: What's the justification for believing that character arrays can't be initialized this way? From what I read in the standard and the gcc bug database (see my answer) it looks to me like character arrays can be initialized this way.

Answer (score 5):

This code is valid C++03 and gcc is simply not conformant here.

The language that allows this syntax for initializing character arrays is the same as allows it for any other type; there are no exceptions that would prohibit it from being used on character arrays. `()` and `=` initialization are equivalent in these cases and the character array should simply be initialized according to 8.5.2.

[Here's](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=43453) a confirmed gcc bug report that covers this.

Comment: +1, indeed a gcc bug. gcc prints the error so *genuinely* that it appears as non-standard construct.

Answer (score 3):

In C++03, that is not possible. Comeau might compile it because of non-Standard extension.

In C++11, you can do this:

```
Foo() : str({'s','t','r'}) {}       //C++11 only
```

Or, you may prefer this intead:

```
class Foo
{
public:
   Foo() {}
   char str[4] = "str"; //in-class initialization (C++11 only)
};
```

Also, you might consider using `std::string` or `std::vector<char>` irrespective of the version of C++ you're using.

Comment: Comeau is a strict ISO-conforming compiler, so i don't sure that this is an extension. Are you sure?

Comment: @NikitaTrophimov: I am dead sure that you cannot do that in C++03.

Comment: The fact that GCC rejects this has been confirmed as a bug in the GCC bug reporter.